# Kubuntu 22.04 stuck in boot process even in recovery mode

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, kubuntu, linux-headers

My Kubuntu 22.04 stuck in boot process even in recovery mode. I suspect it has to do with the recent updates, because after installing them and shutting down, the system never reached login screen again. The list of recently installed packages:

```
2023-02-02 22:34:44 install bat:amd64 <none> 0.19.0-1ubuntu0.1
2023-02-04 10:38:33 install libllvm15:amd64 <none> 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2
2023-02-09 20:22:46 install linux-modules-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 <none> 5.15.0-60.66
2023-02-09 20:22:49 install linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 <none> 5.15.0-60.66
2023-02-09 20:22:50 install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 <none> 5.15.0-60.66
2023-02-09 20:22:58 install linux-headers-5.15.0-60:all <none> 5.15.0-60.66
2023-02-09 20:23:04 install linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic:amd64 <none> 5.15.0-60.66
```

The last ones are regular updates asked to be installed by Kubuntu's Discover.

The boot process stops at this stage:

```
[ OK ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups
```

I don't really mind reinstalling the OS, but is there another way to fix it? Also, what could have happened?

Thank you for your time.

Here is the content of `boot.log`:

```
FAILED Failed to start Rotate log files.
See 'systemctl status logrotate.service' for details.
OK   Started Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
------------ Sat Feb 11 07:54:05 CET 2023 ------------
/dev/sda2: clean, 579416/4890624 files, 7994678/19531264 blocks
FAILED Failed to start Set the console keyboard layout.
FAILED Failed to start Set the console keyboard layout.
FAILED Failed to start Set console font and keymap.
FAILED Failed to start QEMU KVM preparation - module, ksm, hugepages.
FAILED Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
See 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
```

**EDIT:**
I booted with previous kernels, but still no success.

**Output of systemctl status logrotate.service:**

```
○ logrotate.service - Rotate log files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ● logrotate.timer
       Docs: man:logrotate(8)
             man:logrotate.conf(5)
```

**Output of systemctl status apparmor.service:**

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-02-12 10:44:19 CET; 12min ago
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
    Process: 522 ExecStart=/lib/apparmor/apparmor.systemd reload (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 522 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 600us

Feb 12 10:44:19 dave-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
Feb 12 10:44:19 dave-desktop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 12 10:44:19 dave-desktop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 10:44:19 dave-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
```

**Output of systemctl status grub-common.service:**

```
× grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/grub-common.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-02-12 11:33:35 CET; 2min 53s ago
    Process: 579 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ -s /boot/grub/grubenv ] || rm -f /boot/grub/grubenv; mkdir -p /boot/grub (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

Feb 12 11:33:34 dave-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Feb 12 11:33:35 dave-desktop systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 12 11:33:35 dave-desktop systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 12 11:33:35 dave-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Record successful boot for GRUB.
```

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status logrotate.service`

Comment: and `systemctl status apparmor.service`

Comment: Did you do what it told  you to do? See 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.

Comment: I used several previous kernels to boot, but no success. I added the output of `systemctl status` to the question. @RishonJR @David

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apparmor`. If that doesn't work try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-common` and show the output of `systemctl status grub-common.service`.